# What step do they take to solve the limiting distribution

Tags: markov-process

small question. I just can't figure out what step they take to find X1, X2 and X3 (see picture) after I set up the equations.
How do i proceed to go from the 3 diffrent equations to an answer. It should be easy but i dont get it. In the picture is the solution shown, but not the step they take. I hope you guys can help me .

chris[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the linear system by [substitution](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-eighth-grade-math/cc-8th-systems-topic/cc-8th-systems-with-substitution/a/systems-of-equations-with-substitution):

Using the second equation $\pi_2=\frac{1}{2}\pi_1$,you get with the first equation $\pi_1=\frac{1}{4}\pi_1 + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}\pi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\pi_3 = \frac{1}{4}\pi_1 + \frac{1}{6}\pi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\pi_3$ which leads to $\pi_3 = \frac{7}{6}\pi_1$.

Plugging everything in the last equation we get $\pi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\pi_1 + \frac{7}{6}\pi_1=1$ i.e. $\pi_1=\frac{3}{8}$, which then yields $\pi_2=\frac{3}{16}$ and $\pi_3=\frac{7}{16}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helps alot :)